# Подключить или установить ipset в VestaCp

Tags: linux, iptables, vesta

Можно ли как-то использовать ipset в iptables в VestaCp? Если да, то как его подключить или установить?

Comment: Посмотри как это сделано тут. Но там только в консоли необходимо править.
https://www.lowendguide.com/3/networking/iptables-and-vestacp-output-rules-to-allow-dns-lookups/

Comment: Спасибо! Я понял